# How to Inject Activity and Fragment into RecyclerAdapter (Dagger 2)

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

everybody!

I'm quite new to Dagger2, but I really want to understand it. So, first, let's look at the code, of the RecyclerAdapter, that I've implemented with some Application level injections (DbHelper and application Context).

Also, notice, that here we have two instances of DataSetChangeListener and  DataProviderListener:

- **DataSetChangeListener** - is an interface to call some methods in Fragment (which is managing views);
- **DataProviderListener** - is an interface to call methods within Activity (which manages the data model calls);

So, here is the code:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.EmotionsViewHolder> {
    @Inject
    DbHelper mDbHelper;
    @Inject
    Context mContext;

    private ArrayList<String> mItemsList;
    private DataSetChangeListener mDataSetChangeListener;
    private DataProviderListener mDataProviderListener;

    public RecyclerAdapter(DataProviderListener dataProviderListener, DataSetChangeListener listener) {
        App.getAppComponent().inject(this);
        //TODO: Replace with dagger 2 injection
        mDataSetChangeListener = listener;
        mDataProviderListener = dataProviderListener;
        mItemsList = dataProviderListener.getDataSet();
        notifyFragmentAboutDataSetStatus();
    }

    private void notifyFragmentAboutDataSetStatus() {
        if (mItemsList.size() == 0) {
            mDataSetChangeListener.notifyDataSetIsEmpty();
        } else {
            mDataSetChangeListener.notifyDataSetIsNotEmpty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public EmotionsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cbt_element, parent, false);
        return new EmotionsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EmotionsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.mEmotionsTextView.setText(mItemsList.get(position));
        holder.mEditImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editItem(position);
            }
        });
        holder.mDeleteImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                removeItem(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItemsList.size();
    }

    public void addItem(String item) {
        mItemsList.add(item);
        notifyItemInserted(mItemsList.size());
    }

    private void editItem(int position) {
        String currentValue = mItemsList.get(position);
        mDataProviderListener.callEditDialog(currentValue);
    }

    private void removeItem(int position) {
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{mItemsList.get(position)};
        mItemsList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mItemsList.size());

        Uri uri = UniquesContract.EmotionsEntity.CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = UniquesContract.EmotionsEntity.EMOTION_COL + " = ?";
        mContext.getContentResolver().delete(uri, selection, selectionArgs);
    }

    static class EmotionsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mEmotionsTextView;
        ImageView mEditImageView;
        ImageView mDeleteImageView;

        public EmotionsViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mEmotionsTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emotion_text_view);
            mEditImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_item_image_view);
            mDeleteImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_item_image_view);
        }
    }

    public void setNewDataSet(ArrayList<String> list) {
        mItemsList = list;
    }


}
```

I realize, that theoretically I could inject **DataSetChangeListener** and **DataProviderListener**, but how could I do that. Maybe, the point is about creation of a new scope? But I have no idea how to use it. How could I instantiate those two objects inside the RecyclerAdapter, if I even don't have an ability to reference them from the RecyclerAdapter class. Passing instances as a paremethers of constructor is not a DI, already. What should I do here?

Comment: I would rather inject inside fragment / activity, what i need, and pass it as parameter in adapter.

Answer (score 2):

All changes to make your project using more Dagger and Dependency Injection depends on your whole project structure! But, if you like to inject those two interfaces you can write a provider method for RecyclerAdapter and inject those interfaces to it inside your module:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public RecyclerAdapter provideRecyclerAdapter(DataProviderListener dataProviderListener, DataSetChangeListener listener) {
    return new RecyclerAdapter(dataProviderListener, listener);
}
```

> note that: another provider or your module constructor must provide
>   these interfaces while injection.

You can also do Constructor Injection by adding @Inject annotation to your RecyclerAdapter constructor like this:

```
@Inject
public RecyclerAdapter(DataProviderListener dataProviderListener, DataSetChangeListener listener) {
        App.getAppComponent().inject(this);
        ...
```

You can learn more about using dagger in Android project by reading this sample project I have done:

> https://github.com/mmirhoseini/fyber_mobile_offers